# Unity2D tile drawing on tilemap shows up in scene view but not in game? Manually placed tiles work fine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity where the player can draw tiles on a tilemap during runtime. Clicking on a button enables the drawing capability, clicking and dragging sets tiles on an empty tilemap, and clicking another button exits the drawing mode. My issue is that the tiles don't show up in play mode. If you switch to scene view, the tiles appear to have been drawn correctly, but the tilemap looks empty in play mode.

Here is the code that controls this functionality:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PathDrawSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tilemap tilemap;
    public Tile tile; 

    private bool isDrawing = false; // Indicate if drawing is in progress

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDrawing)
        {
            // Check if the left mouse button is held down
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                // Get the mouse position in world space
                Vector3 mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

                // Get the cell position in the Tilemap based on the mouse position
                Vector3Int cellPos = tilemap.WorldToCell(mouseWorldPos);

                // Set the tile at the cell position
                tilemap.SetTile(cellPos, tile);

                // Refresh the tile to update the display
                tilemap.RefreshTile(cellPos);
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartDrawing() //assigned to a button
    {
        isDrawing = true;
    }

    public void StopDrawing() //assigned to a button
    {
        isDrawing = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

I was expecting the tiles to show up in both play mode and the scene view. I verified all the sort layers/orders should be correct and I manually drew the tiles on the tilemap (in editing mode, not during runtime) and those show up fine, so it shouldn't be a rendering/sort issue.

Comment: Check the `z` coordinate of the newly drawn tiles. They may have been drawn behind the 2d camera.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues my tilemap is at z=0 so wouldn't cellPos (and therefore my drawn tiles) also be at z=0 along with the manually placed tiles?